# python - os.remove() a file then create a new one but creation date is not updated

Tags: python, matplotlib, operating-system

I try to overwrite a figure with matplotlib together with os.remove() using below code. Why is the creation date not updated? (I am using Anaconda Prompt)

the code is source from here: [Matplotlib Savefig will NOT overwrite old files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49039581/matplotlib-savefig-will-not-overwrite-old-files)

some suggest using `os.remove(os.path.join(path, del_file))` as here:[Python os.remove fails to remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48758703/python-os-remove-fails-to-remove) But that didn't work for me.

Is there a way to code up something to update the creation date?

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#make figure
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')

#save
strFile = "./figs/my_plot.jpg"
if os.path.isfile(strFile):
   os.remove(strFile)   # Opt.: os.system("rm "+strFile)
plt.savefig(strFile)
```

Edits: I am using windows system.

Comment: This should update the creation date.

Comment: Your code works as you expect in my machine (Linux KDE Neon 5.22, Python 3.8.2).

Comment: The question you linked to is for when the remove fails, but you're not getting that error.

Comment: I am using windows system.

Comment: Try using the full path to the file. Maybe you're not writing the file you think you are.

Comment: I'm using python 3.9.12 on win10 and I have the same problem. os.remove() works as expected, when it is run alone (F9, spyder)

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same strange behavior writing to google drive folder on my windows machine. I use `os.remove` and then using pickle to save file using 'w' (which I can confirm the content changes).

It works if i delete it and put `time.sleep(30)` after the deletion. I assume the cloud  drive is catching up, hopefully this helps you, I am not sure what the time needed for it to catch up, likely far below 30 seconds but 30 should be plenty of time so its a safe bet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around, that worked for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4996407/10571437

with

```
import time
newtime = time.time()
```